# API 19 : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class SeekBar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the following layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context="mtronics.alertme.HomePage">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSpeedSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Limit : 0 Km/h"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/speedView" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarSpeedSet"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_fillet_background"
        android:max="200"
        android:progress="0"
        android:thumb="@drawable/icon_seek_thumb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSpeedSet" >
    </SeekBar>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listAlerts"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarSpeedSet">
    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Drawable files 
**icon_seek_thumb.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape>
            <size
                android:height="40dp"
                android:width="40dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_seek_thumb"/>
</layer-list>
```

**ic_seek_thumb.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorText"
        android:pathData="...."/>
</vector>
```

**With above layout i am getting following error only for API 19, for higher it is working

NOTE: If i remove android:thumb from seekbar , it works for API 19 also**

I am getting following error when i try to execute in API 19

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class SeekBar
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for VectorDrawables was added to the framework in API 21 so they are not supported in API 19 - hence the crash.

The support library provides a backported version `VectorDrawableCompat` which you are able to use on lower Android versions.  Unfortunately if I remember correctly it doesn't hook into the seekbar thumb when inflating from xml.

To get around this you have to create the thumb Drawable in java and set it to your Seekbar manually.

Firstly make sure you have AppCompat in your `build.gradle`:

```
api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
```

Then in the java class where you are using the `Seekbar` create a new method to set the thumb.  The following should be equivalent to your original xml:

```
private void initThumbDrawable() {

    final int size = convertDpToPixel(40);

    GradientDrawable square = new GradientDrawable();
    square.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    square.setSize(size, size);
    square.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    VectorDrawableCompat thumb = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable. ic_seek_thumb, null);

    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {square, thumb});

    seekBar.setThumb(layerDrawable);
}

private int convertDpToPixel(int dp) {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
}
```

It would probably simpler if you included the padding into your vector rather than using a layer list!

Finally be sure to remove the:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/icon_seek_thumb"
```

from your layout xml file

Comment: Thanks Jahnold, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Jahnold,I just saw my old code where in i am using drawable for seekbar thumb, That code is working for API 15 to API 19.

Comment: Yep you can use a drawable as long as it's not a VectorDrawable or contains a VectorDrawable

Answer (score 1):

Once i had the same problem. I fixed it placing all drawable files under **drawable** folder. Mine issue was some drawable files were present only in **drawable -xxdpi** not in **drawable** folder where lower API level looks for the file..

Replace all your files on drawable folder that may fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah :P I had some resources in v24 while I was testing on v21 :)